# Express Redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the user after the signup has been validated. See the code below, it never worked with everything i have tried. I also tried on the front end part with

```
<Redirect=to"/login" />
```

it wasn't a success either. I'm trying to redirect to : http://localhost:3000/login, the backend is currently on port 5000.
I also that those errors coming in the console :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/login' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/users/signup') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET http://localhost:3000/login net::ERR_FAILED

createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:99)
```

My first thought was that the header is not set, but it is in my app.js

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});
```

Thanks in advance

```
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10).then((hash) => {
    const user = {
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hash,
    };
    User.create(user)
      .then(() => {
        res.redirect(301, 'http://localhost:3000/login');
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(500).json({ message: "Impossible de créer l'utilisateur. " + error }));
  });
};
```

Comment: `res.redirect` is redirecting your backend request to `http://localhost:3000/login`. But the request is initiated on `localhost:5000`. Trying to redirect to another port can cause CORS errors.  I think it is better if you can implement the redirect on the front end by checking the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res.status(200).redirect('login');
```

(EDIT) This will return 200 and redirect the user from the backend.

This is my solution from the front-end, if you'd like it.

On the frontend, you could redirect to your desired location using `window.location.replace('/login')` after the express returns a value.

What I mean by this is after you've validated the user on your Express API, return 200 via `res.status(200).send()` to let your front end know that this user is allowed to be redirected.

An example with jQuery:

Front-End

```
<script>
$.get('http://localhost:3000/login', function(data, status, jqXHR) {
    if (status === 200) {
         window.location.replace('redirect-location.html')
    } else {
        // What to do if the status isn't 200
    }
})
</script>
```

Back-End:

```
app.get('/login', (res, req, err) => {
     // Validate
     const result = validatefunction() // true if login matches, false otherwise
    if (result) {
        res.status(200).send()
    } else if (!result) {
        res.status(400).send()
    } else {
        res.status(500).send() 
    }
})
```

Hope I've helped.